# How can I find the highest value in a .txt file?

Tags: python, file

I'm sending this because I'm stucked on a code that I stayed the whole day trying to get it.

It's a program in python that reads a .txt file with lots of floating point values (100 million+) and takes the highest and the lowest value from it.

I had lot's of problems, the first says that I couldn't convert string to floating point to compare the values.

And the new code don't show the values.

Some details:

- The lines have multiple values, I tried to use split to take them.
- All the numbers are floating point

here's the code:

```
with open('gmm_data.txt') as f:
    array = []
    minim = 99999999999999
    maxim = -99999999999999
    for line in f: # read rest of lines
        array.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
    if(array[0] > maxim):
        maxim = array[0]
    elif(array[0] < minim):
        minim = array[0]

print (maxim)
print (minim)
```

Comment: could you provide sample of input and how long your input is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good clean way to do it:

```
def min_and_max(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)

    # Assumes at least two items in iterator
    minim, maxim = sorted((next(iterator), next(iterator)))

    for item in iterator:
        if item < minim:
            minim = item
        elif item > maxim:
            maxim = item

    return (minim, maxim)


with open('gmm_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    values = (float(value_str) for line in f for value_str in line.split())
    minim, maxim = min_and_max(values)

print(maxim)
print(minim)
```

Remember, `float`'s can be imprecise; consider using `decimal.Decimal()` if you need more accuracy with the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You say you have over million floating point values in your file, if so you should not be reading entire file into memory and storing them as floats.

Instead you should read each line, convert all the values in a single line to float , and then try to find the maximum/minimum from it and then store a variable for denoting the maximum and minimum element across the file and check if the maximum and minimum of each line is greater/lesser than those values and replace accordingly.

To initialize, you can initialize maximum value as `float('-inf')` . Example -

```
with open('gmm_data.txt') as f:
    maxf = float('-inf')
    minf = float('inf')
    for line in f: # read rest of lines
        if line.strip():
            arr = [float(x) for x in line.split()])
            maxa = max(arr)
            mina = min(arr)
            if maxa > maxf:
                maxf = maxa
            if mina < minf:
                minf = mina
```

Comment: If line is empty, then arr list will be empty. When we try to find max or min of list, then it will return "ValueError : max() arg is an empty sequence" .

Comment: @Igor, please check the length of list before finding max or min.

Comment: @DineshPundkar Fixed it in my code as well , checking `line.strip()` to be non empty before creating arr/taking max/min.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your comparison step you are want to access the **last** element of your array (since this is where new values are `append`ed; this is achieved in Python with `array[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the whole file .You could use this method.

**Code:**

```
def conversion(num):
    try:
        num=float(num)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

with open('a.txt') as f:
    numbers=[float(num) for line in f for num in line.split() if conversion(num) ]
minim = 99999999999999
maximum= -99999999999999
if numbers:
    if max(numbers)>maximum:
        maximum=max(numbers)
    if min(numbers)<minim:
        minim=min(numbers)
print "maximum value:"+str(maximum)
print "minimum value:"+str(minim)
```

If your file is very large.Then you could use this.

**Code2:**

```
def conversion(num):
    try:
        num=float(num)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

minim = 99999999999999
maximum= -99999999999999
with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers=[float(num) for num in line.split() if conversion(num) ]
    if numbers:
        if max(numbers)>maximum:
            maximum=max(numbers)
        if min(numbers)<minim:
            minim=min(numbers)
print "maximum value:"+str(maximum)
print "minimum value:"+str(minim)
```